# Maven dependency on a commit to a git repo?

Tags: git, maven, dependencies, commit

In Cabal for Haskell - we can generate a new version of a project [based upon a given commit from a git repo using Max's Bot](http://maxsbot.net/).

Is it possible to do this for Java projects using Maven?

Answer (score 0):

As I understand it, Maven dependencies must come from a specific version or a "snapshot" version, which is a version in development. While historically snapshot versions automatically gave you the *latest* version rather than a *specific* version, in recent versions of Maven, snapshot versions are timestamped.

That means your project dependencies can be configured to point to a specific snapshot, which will not change even if the project releases new snapshots.

You can run a local snapshot build of the project at the specific git commit you need, and install that to `~/.m2/repository` and/or a private maven repository, and then refer to that timestamped version in your dependencies.